# Missing values in Cognos Report prompt

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have a problem with missing values in a Cognos Report Studio value prompt.

I have two queries
Query 1 contains business unit and sales (measure)
Query 2 contains only business unit (no measures)

Query 1 shows all the possible business units and their sales, while query 2 for some reason shows only half of the business units.

On the prompt page, I have a value prompt where I want to display all the business units. However, I get the same result (only the business units from query 2) even if I use query 1 as source for the prompt.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that Query 1 doesn't contain duplicate business units? By default, queries optimize output to eliminate duplicates. Query 2, since there is only one data item, will automatically eliminate duplicate business units. The same will happen if you use Query 1 as your value prompt source as only the data item specified will be included in the query to retrieve the values.